# include_once 'PEAR.php' throws "The connection was reset"

Tags: php, pear

Here is standart code from the package

```
@include_once 'PEAR.php';
if (!class_exists('PEAR_Error')) {
    include_once 'FileMaker/PEAR.php';
}
```

on this line `include_once 'PEAR.php';` server fails and throws

> The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too
>   busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages,
>   check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network
>   is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is
>   permitted to access the Web.

whats is wrong and how to fix that? I can't just comment this line as well as there are a lot such insertions.

Comment: Which PHP / PEAR version are you using? Which web server?

Comment: php 5.3.15. Pear isn't installed.

Comment: Normally Pear comes bundled with php. Why do you require the PEAR.php if it is not installed? Do you use apache? If yes, what does the apache error.log say? What's in the php log? Can you add the statement `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your code?

Comment: its require package. So server fails because it cant include pear?

Comment: add the `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` statement before the `require_once 'PEAR.php';` . what does it say?

Comment: no errors seems server just fails. Pear installed but phpinfo says --without-pear. Maybe need reconfigure it?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which web server? (Sorry for answering questions with questions :) Need information to reproduce the problem)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is php bug. So if I use `$obj =& new Obj` sometimes it lead to some unexplainable error. So if you use old packages I suggest update them with newer versions or fix them by yourself stripping `&`